# R define dataset

Tags: r

This is probably a stupid question but, is there a way to define a dataset in R to save time by avoiding typing dataset$ before the names of all the variables over and over again?

E.g. so I would type :

```
varA<-varB+varC
```

instead of :

```
dataset$varA<-dataset$varB+dataset$varC
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attach(dataset)`

but note that [this is discouraged](http://www.r-bloggers.com/to-attach-or-not-attach-that-is-the-question/) if you're writing code to be reused.

Comment: Thanks. Clicking on the link, I can see how this method could lead to lots of confusion.

Comment: you still need `dataset$VarA` on the LHS though

Answer (score 3):

`attach()` is one way however,

`transform` is a nice way to get rid of `$`

```
dat <- read.table(text = " varA  varB  varC
                                 0     1     1
                                 0     1     1
                                 0     1     1", header=TRUE)

dat <- transform(dat, varA = varB + varC)
```

[similar to](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/plyr.pdf) `mutate()` in `plyr` which:

> *seems to be considerably faster than transform for large data frames.*

Comment: also, `with` and `within`